# How does the Google Elevation API 'explode' a polyline into equidistant points?

Tags: javascript, google-elevation-api

The Elevation API provided by Google, uses two parameters for requesting height along a path: path and samples. The path is the lat and lng of the starting and the finish points and the samples is the sample points along a path for which to return elevation data. So the path is divided into an ordered set of equidistant points along the path, which are sent back to the client as an array of lat, lng and elevation for each point. This can be useful for visualizing elevation profiles or such.

I have seen other open-source alternatives for the Google Elevation API, however, none of them has an easy way to provide a samples parameter, so if one wants to achieve the same, you simply have to somehow 'explode' the path yourself into multiple equidistant points and send this array as part of the URL to the back-end.

Is there a library or algorithm I should consider when splitting the path (which is usually of type LineString / polyline) into equidistant points? In general, how should I approach this problem?

Comment: Please mention what open source alternatives you have already studied.